# "I have an answer for your question, but you might not like it."

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

What would be a single English word that could reflect the phrase (if such a word exists):

> I have an answer for your question, but you might not like it.

or

> We corresponded, but you might not like the outcome.

The word shouldn't be an exact equivalent, but must reflect the situation as closely as possible.

Comment: A *single* word? That's a tall order.

Comment: What research have you done already?

Comment: @MetaEd discussed it with collegues and we couldn't come up with a suitable word to reflect the situation.

Comment: @RegDwightАΑA He used the `phrase-requests` tag, not the `single-word-requests` tag.

Comment: Can you give an example of a sentence in which you would want to use such a word?

Comment: @Luke: Regardless of the tag, the question asks explicitly for a single word.

Comment: @Luke apologies, didn't know the "single-word-requests" tag existed. Fixed.

Comment: I'm really tempted to answer with a pun...

Comment: @Gorpik post the pun into the comments :-)

Comment: @ChrisW I believe that the pithiest alternative is to flip the other party the bird/v-sign :P

Comment: @ChrisW: I have an answer for your question, but you might not like it...

Answer (score 5):

It really depends on the context of the response or outcome.

However, if I was starting correspondence addressing a question and I *knew* that they wouldn't be too pleased with the answer, I would probably start with **"Unfortunately"**.

It probably doesn't correlate directly with what you say but I can think of enough scenarios to warrant me suggesting it.

> Dear Sir, I bought this tent and it leaks.  I would like a refund.
>
> Dear Customer.  **Unfortunately** we can't offer refunds after 28 days.

or

> Can I bring my dog to the hotel?
>
> **Unfortunately** our policy does not allow pets in the room

Comment: The term **regretably** conveys something similar and adds a sympathetic tone.

Comment: @bib, **[regrettably](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/regrettably)** might do so

Comment: @jwpat7 - If I am going to keep hanging out on this site, I had  better get better at spelling & avoiding typos.

Answer (score 3):

This question reminds me of some *I've got some good news, and some bad news* jokes.

As for getting it all into one word, you might consider ***jeremiad***, as in:

> I have a *jeremiad* for you.

According to [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/jeremiad#jeremiad_4):

> **jeremiad**: a long sad complaint or list of things that have gone wrong

It's neither a well-known nor common term, and perhaps it's not an exact fit, either.  Then again, as RegDwight said in his comment, it's an awful lot of meaning to pack into one word, and that's the best I could muster.

Comment: I'll be adding this word into my list of words to use! Thanks!

Comment: Please tell me you didn't know that off the top of your head ...

Comment: Wiktionary's definition of *[jeremiad](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jeremiad)*, "A long speech or prose work that bitterly laments the state of society and its morals, and often contains a prophecy of its coming downfall", is more informative and accurate, I think, on how *jeremiad* actually is used.  A *jeremiad* is more of a reproving diatribe than merely a list of things wrong.

Comment: Jeremiad is a wonderful word, but I would certainly not recommend it in this instance. A jeremiad is, as @jwpat7 says, a diatribe, lament, harangue, or rant.

Comment: @jwpat7 & Mark Beadles: I totally agree with both of you. I knew it was a stretch when I posted it, hence my disclaimer. Also, I'd almost added a note about how the word would be typically used to describe a lament, but, after re-reading the O.P.'s question, I thought that "I have an answer for your question, but you might not like it" could, conceivably, be followed by a lament, depending upon the topic being discussed.

Answer (score 3):

You've requested a "word that could reflect the phrase (if such a word exists): 'I have an answer for your question, but you might not like it'".  If this is not a trick question, *mirror* is the word you want.  Or if you mean, reflect the *sense* of the phrase, then 
*[let-down](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/let-down)* (a noun, idiomatic for "A disappointment or anticlimax") is suitable.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

> I’m sorry to disappoint you, but …

Comment: Not a single word or anything near that...